# how to display multiple records in multiple textboxes but from same database vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

[my vb purchase form output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x35O4.png)

*The problem is where, i wanted to choose different products in each textboxes,
but the values is added into both textboxes equally and I cannot add seperately. Since im new to vb because of a school project. I do REALLY hope for a solution. I need to display 3values in 3textboxes,but for now i have tried in 2texboxes only. I hope this explains.*

**this is my coding for the database to textboxes output :**

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.CurrentRow
    Try

        txtprod1.Text = row.Cells(1).Value.ToString()
        txtPrice.Text = row.Cells(2).Value.ToString()
        txtqty.Text = row.Cells(3).Value.ToString()

    Catch ex As Exception
        yLoad()
    End Try

    Try

        txtprod2.Text = row.Cells(1).Value.ToString()
        txtprice2.Text = row.Cells(2).Value.ToString()
        txtqty2.Text = row.Cells(3).Value.ToString()

    Catch ex As Exception
        yLoad()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: You're getting the same values because you never change what `row` is pointing to nor the cell indexes. Are you trying to copy data from 2 separate DataGridViewRows into the textboxes, or is the data all from 1 single DataGridViewRow?

Comment: You should change the current row in order to copy data from different rows. And why are you using the cell content click event?

Comment: What do you want to happen when a user selects a 4th row? I would guess you want to go back to the first set of controls so the three most current selections are displayed.

Comment: hi @soohoonigan, yes im calling the same datagridviewrows in other textboxes, but to be able to choose seperatly is what i wanted in each textboxes.

Comment: hi @Mary, sorry im not sure what your asking ...but its actully abut choosing products from the product database into 3 textboxes(with price) to choose for purchasing...so...if im choosing one product in first textbox..i want to choose another product in the other two. but im still calling out the same rows of products.

Comment: hi @preciousbetine, i dont know how is that done because, i follow tutorials online only...tats how it was done there

Comment: Please can you give an example of the desired output

Comment: @preciousbetine, the output required is there will be a product datagridview and 3 textboxes to select the product from the grid (with pricetextbox to autofill). i require to choose 2more different products from the same datagrid and save it to purchase.so total of 3products to choose from same datagrid. im sorry i could not attach any image here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Private Sub DataGridView1_RowEnter(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowEnter
        If Not IsLoaded Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Static CurrentCount As Integer
        If CurrentCount < 3 Then
            CurrentCount += 1
        Else
            CurrentCount = 1
        End If
        Dim s As String = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value.ToString
        'Cell 1 happens to be the Name property in the grid I am using
        Select Case CurrentCount
            Case 1
                TextBox1.Text = s
            Case 2
                TextBox2.Text = s
            Case 3
                TextBox3.Text = s
            Case Else
                MessageBox.Show("Error")
        End Select
        'CurrentRow is a day late and a dollar short when using the RowEnter event
        'Dim s As String = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString
End Sub

Dim IsLoaded As Boolean = False

Private Sub DataGridViewTest_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
        IsLoaded = True
End Sub
```

The IsLoaded Form level (class level) variable keeps the selection from happening until you change the selection.

A Static variable will keep its value between calls to the Sub.

The If statement keeps track of how many times the Sub has been called so we know what text box to fill in.

We get the cell we are after by using the DataGridViewCellArgs (e) and the RowIndex property. You can set a few more variables with other cell values and then assign them to your textboxes in the select case.